# Android InApp billing V3 - Subscription validation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In the documentation of the Android [InApp billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) is written `With In-app Billing Version 3, the failed or expired subscription is no longer returned when you call getPurchases.`

What does this exactly mean? 
And is it possible in V3 to validate a subscription through the [developer API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#play-dev-api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever your application needs to know all purchased content by the user it has to call one api call named `getPurchases()`. This will return you an `json` object having details of all product-ids which the user has already purchased.

**Yes**, you can validate or cancel subscription from your back-end server using http based APIs.